# Is this possible?

Tags: riddle

what has four legs when it is **young**, 
Two legs when it is **middle age**,
And three legs when it is **old?**

Comment: why did you answer your own question so quick after it was posted?  Usually people will leave some time for others to try and answer

Comment: @puzzledPig Maybe that's the riddle...

Answer (score 0):

> Babies crawl on **four legs**
>  Teens/children walk on **two legs**
>  Old people sometimes use walking sticks which makes **three legs**!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Firstly, please don't post riddles that have already been posted here before, especially when they're so well-known. Secondly, please don't answer your own puzzles within three minutes. That's not what this site is for. Thirdly, please hide your answers within spoiler tags, so as not to spoil the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves. Thank you.

Comment: @F1Krazy I could not have put it better :D